# What is a better political voting method?

Tags: sampling, expectation-maximization, decision-theory, voting-system

We are in a season where some major elections are happening (e.g. U.S. elections) and I find it interesting to address.

### Objective

When we decide "better", we need to define an objective. To be clear, my definition of better is as follows:

> *Definition:* A voting method $m_1$ is better than another voting method $m_2$ only if $m_1$ leads to higher mean lifespan expectancy in the upcoming 20 years for those who vote.

*Note 1:* this definition is not subject to change, and is not a question. Kindly assume that this objective is true when giving any answer. Therefore, suggesting alternative objectives is off-topic.

*Note 2:* suppose that elections are actually meaningful. E.g. do not discuss facts such as lobbyiests.

### A Common Voting Method: Simple Majority Voting

The population is defined to be the set of all living citizens that are eligible for voting. We then choose the president that the majority want.

The assumption here is that the president that is chosen by the majority is one that will lead to maximize our objective better than any other candidate president.

This means that over-represented kinds of people in the population will have their votes translate into actions. If the majority of the population are of kind "idiot", then we will choose a decision that idiots think are best. If kind "genius" is a minority, then its vote will not translate into actions (unless geniuses happen to agree with idiots; possibly for different reasons, but if wrong thinking leads to right decision then who cares).

### Alternative Voting Method 1

The population is the space of possible decisions. In this case this set is $\mathcal{D} = \{choose president_1, choose president_2, \ldots, choose president_n\}$.

Additionally, we define another population of citizens $\mathcal{C}$. We partition this set into various strata based on the kind of citizens. Suppose that all citizens in $\mathcal{C}$ are of kinds that are definiable by the binary parameters $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_m$ only. This means that we will have $2^m$ partitions/strata. Our strata is $\mathcal{S} = \{s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_{2^m}\}$.

Then, for any stratum $s_i \in \mathcal{S}$, we find the majority vote of citizens that fall within stratum $s_i$ (i.e. the most popular president candidate in stratum $s_i$. Let $v_i$ be the majority vote of stratum $s_i$.

Finally, we list all strata votes $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_{2^m}$, and choose the most popular vote from this list.

This alternative voting method assumes that all *kinds* of voters have equal power in deciding the right action. Therefore, "geniuses", "almost-geniuses", "normal", "almost-idiots", and "idiots" are guaranteed to be equally powerful.

### Alternative Voting Method 2

This is identical to the alternative voting method 1, except for the following distinction: instead of assuming that vote $v_i$ of stratum $s_i$ has an equal power in deciding the final chosen president as any other stratum, we follow a weighted approach such that $v_i$ has a higher power in choosing the president than another vote $v_l$ only the stratum $s_i$ contains citizens of a kind that is smarter than the kind in the stratum $s_l$.

### Other Voting Methods

Feel free to define other voting methods if they help answering the questions.

### Questions

- Q1) How to decide which voting method is a better method to maximize the optimization objective?
- Q2)

  - A1) Using the method in the answer of (Q1) and assuming that there is a deterministic answer: Which voting method is one that maximizes the optimization objective above?
  - A2) Using the method in the answer of (Q1) but assuming that there is no deterministic answer: Which voting method is one that is more likely to maximize the optimization objective?
- Q3) Justify your answer for questions (Q1) and (Q2).

## Hints on How You Might Want to Answer This

This question is fundamentally a statistical inference problem where your goal is finding the decision that is shall maximize the optimization objective.

For example, by asking the votes of people from the population, you are doing an identical job to ensemble learning algorithms, such as Random Forests where votes are averaged from various randomly grown decision trees. Except that you replace humans by decision trees.

Such inference usually happens by:

- Analyzing some dataset (if you have one),
- OR (if you don't have such dataset, or don't find it convenient to build one) theoretically discuss the pros and cos of the various inference methods, and then try to justify why you think that the pros and cons of some inference method are better suited for the scenario at hand.

Similar to other machine learning problems, this is a question that requires some thinking and the addition of extra assumptions. There is no theorem or a deterministic equation that you can use solve this deterministically without assuming extra things. Thus you are free to suggest the addition of extra assumptions and constraints to justify your solution.

Then, if your assumptions and constraints seem plausible, I will consider your answer to be the correct answer.

Comment: I have a hard time seeing how this question is on-topic for this board.

Comment: "Higher lifespan expectancy" for whom and in what sense (median, mean, upper quartile, for the longest living 10,000)? For the citizens of the country that is voting? For some of them? For the population of the world?

Comment: @Björn, higher mean life expectancy for those in the population of citizens that is voting.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, is there any reason why you think so? To me it appears related for reasons 1) it has to do with sampling methods, 2) inferring more optimal decisions (thus statistical inferencer).

Comment: I think a well-formulated question of this type might be on topic, but this one does not seem to be sufficiently clear or quantitative to be amenable to analysis. Among other problems, "The assumption here is that the president that is chosen by the majority is one that will lead to maximize our objective better than any other candidate president" is not a quantitative objective and does not appear amenable to any kind of relevant analysis. There is no formula in evidence that could be used to translate votes or voting methods into values of any objective function.

Comment: @whuber, can you please give examples on promising directions to form this into a well-formulated question? So far I don't understand how the objective is not quantitative. As far as I know, the mean lifespan expectancy in next 20 years for voting citizens is a number, and therefore quantitative as far as I can tell.

Comment: Could you exhibit an explicit formula showing how a choice of voting method can be used to compute a *numerical* value of an objective function?

Comment: @whuber, I can if I have a training/learning dataset to start estimating probability density functions. You are allowed to assume some PDF and state the specifics of the assumptions.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell what you're writing about. Since your post refers to voting methods, voters, strata, kinds of voters, candidates, and life expectancies, it's impossible to tell what your PDFs would be referring to. You don't seem to have described any dataset that would comprise all this information. I don't see any definite way in which any choice of voting method could be related to life expectancies.  If you would like to get reasonable answers, then it is your duty to clarify these things, not for us to guess what it all might mean.

Comment: @whuber, I think there are some people who are in the business of designing sampling methods (we call it voting here) and generalize conclusions based on their observations on whatever datasets. And I think these people don't need datasets about every problem domain. They just generalize things and spew out conclusions in little nice boxes for others to use. I think you guys could do the same here. It's a complicated question that requires more thinking than usual. I don't ask here questions to solve homeworks, thus you see me ask more creative questions that require out of box thinking.

Comment: We appreciate such questions.  We only ask that they be formulated with sufficient clarity that they can be answered.

Comment: @whuber, added a section on "Hints on How You Might Want to Answer This" -- is it fine now?

Comment: It's too broad for our format.  We just don't answer questions that are so open-ended and undefined.

Comment: @whuber, it is defined, but in a broad manner. It's sad that you are not allowing open questions to exist in stackexchange. We are now limited to too specific questions that don't have much room for creativity. This is terrible.